# Clarification on "After You..." card text

Tags: guillotine

In Guillotine the "After You..." card states "Put the noble at the front of the line into another player's score pile." Is the card put into the other players score pile the executed noble for this turn and thus end the turn or does the player who played the card then get to collect the next noble at the front of the line ending his/her turn? So is this noble executed instead of or in addition to the noble the player would normally collect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each turn you *may* play an action, and then *must* collect a nobel.

Unless the action caused the Day to end then you *must* collect a nobel of your own after playing the card.

*(Guillotine was designed and published by Wizards of the Coast and it comes as no surprise to me that the mechanic is so reliant on wording. It certainly makes settling arguments easy... if you're a lawyer!)*